# I can't connect php with ms-access db

Tags: php, ms-access

I already tried some tutorials and some other codes from this site but nothing really solved my problem:

```
<?php
  $db = database;
  $con = ("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$db");
  $conn = odbc_connect($con, "", "", "SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC");
  if (!file_exists($db))
  {
    die("Banco de dados não encontrado.");
  }
  else{ 
    echo "sas"; 
  }
  $sql = odbc_exec($con,"select * from tb_produto where Valor = '434'");
?>
```

Gives me the following error:

> odbc_connect() expects parameter 4 to be int, string given in -- on
>   line 4

Comment: for what purpose you use ms-access intead mysql?

Comment: Your db is named 'database'? If Valor is a number field, don't use apostrophes around 434.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]! Seems like you didn't understood the error message, wjat sjows you are quite new to coding.  I wouls duggest you starting with a * clean'  language like Java (Android) or C# as you can't you them, without understanding what is going on. PHP is extremly ' dirty'. No matter what you doing, I doesn't complain (except you don't know what an int is) and many people using it, are weak in coding, what leads to bad code you copled, like Excel on Ms Office. Bad code (but it seems to  works) gets copied and floods us (-Select->.Selection).

Comment: The error message want to tell you, that the fourth parameter (argument) of`odbc_connect`must be an int(eger), a number. You provided a string (text between double-quotes), but SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC`is a constant, representing an integer-number . Afer you solved that you will find out that the  code still doesn't work. First line`database'`is a function (variables start with`$`.Second line has unwanted parenthesis, ....

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example taken from the manual [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-exec.php)

```
$Conn = odbc_connect("db_name","","",SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);

$result=odbc_exec($Conn,"select * from usuaris;");
```

Comment: actually, i already tried that. And the error now is: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Nome da fonte de dados n�o encontrado e nenhum driver padr�o especificado

Answer (score 0):

`SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC` is a predefined constant and should be used directly and not passed as a string.

```php
$conn = odbc_connect($con,"","",SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);
```

Note the lack of quotes.